# Lookup values in a table with duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

[image]

The image has the requirements. Can anybody please help me out in this?

Comment: Can you explain your problem properly in words also in order to understand what are you looking for

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Pivot table won't work since the size of the table is huge.

Comment: Table 1 
  
ID   
AA   
BB   
CC 
  
Table 2   

ID Category Value 
CC X 12 
CC Y 1 
CC Z 6
AA X 2 
AA Y 5 
AA Z 1 
BB X 3 
BB Y 7 
BB Z 10 
 
   
Result   

ID X Y Z
AA 2 5 1
BB 3 7 10
CC 12 1 6

Comment: I mean split Category column and Value column to three columns, where you want the result what are the references...

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify `Table2` and insert a new column C before `Value` (will be column D)
In C2 write:

`=A2&B2`  (example AAX will be the result) and drag it down

In the Result Table Under `X` write:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&$B$1,Table2!$C$2:$D$10,2,false),"")`
and drag it down

Under `Y` use:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&$C$1,Table2!$C$2:$D$10,2,false),"")`
and drag it down

Under `Z` write:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&$D$1,Table2!$C$2:$D$10,2,false),"")`
and drag it down

C2:D10 is the new array in Table2 after inserting the new column in C and combining column A and B
A2 is the first `AA` in Result
B1 is `X` in Result
C1 is `Y` in Result
D1 is `Z` in Result
The $ before reference to fix it so you can drag it and it will not change
IFERROR in case no value to return empty "" instead of error (#N/A or Value!)